# Difference between cache miss rate metrics

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, processor

In [appendix B](https://www.inkling.com/read/computer-architecture-hennessy-5th/appendix-b/section-b-1) of Patterson & Hennessy, two different cache miss rate metrics are introduced: `misses/instruction`, and `misses/memory-reference`.

An equation relating the two is derived:

> misses/instruction = misses/memory-reference * memory-references/instruction

They go on to describe the advantages of the `misses/instruction` metric:

> The advantage of misses per instruction is that it is independent of the hardware implementation. For example, speculative processors fetch about twice as many instructions as are actually committed, which can artificially reduce the miss rate if measured as misses per memory reference rather than per instruction.

How is the above possible? Assuming the `misses/memory-reference` ratio is artificially lowered in speculative processors, wouldn't the equation imply that the same happens to `misses/instruction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because one should use misses per committed instructions (not misses per fetched instructions, not misses per executed instructions).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how the distinction you make influences the equation above? Thanks!

Comment: In speculative processors, misses per executed instructions are usually lower than misses per committed instructions. misses/memory-reference takes into account executed instructions (which could commit or not). I wouldn't use that equation for speculative processors. Perhaps, I am missing something, but this is my understanding.